# How to add attributes to TD/TR from new row of bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

Currently  I have project using [bootstrap-table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table). I have problem when add new row with attribute. To insert new row I used code below:

```
    var row = ({
                  name: "test name",
                  type: "Organisation",
                  status: 'Active',
                  action: ''
                });
     $('#table-home').bootstrapTable('append', row);
```

I want to add attribute also to the new row. I am currently used jQuery like below:

```
                var newRow = $('#table-home tr:last');
                var firstTd = newRow.find('td:first');
                var lastTd = newRow.find('td:last');
                newRow.attr("data-catid",categoryName);
                newRow.attr("data-assetdetail_id",data);
                firstTd.attr("data-remove-link","#");
                firstTd.attr("data-edit-link","#");
```

But that's attribute will lost after I insert/append new row again. After I sort the table my attributes will lost too.  actually how to add attribute to new row of bootstrap-table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already read all documentation and I can not found how to do that. But today, after I experiment use console.log to check what object/data inside every row in bootstrap-table I solved my problem with code below:

```
            const row= ({
                    name: RiskName,
                    type: "Risk Type",
                    status: 'Active',
                    action: '',
                    _data:({"uniqueid":data.id,
                        "key":0,
                        "id":data.id,
                        "status":"Active",
                        "type": "Risk Type",
                    }),
                    _action_data:({"delete-link":"",
                        "edit-name":RiskName,
                    })
                });
```

**_data** is data attribute for the row (example `<tr data-id="val">`)

**_action_data** is data attribute for the column which named *action*(exampled result `<td data-tag="val">`)

Comment: Hey, i don't understand your solution, where do you modify the row for the table?

Comment: @RickS      I not just modify the row, but add new row with the custom attributes.  $('#table-home').bootstrapTable('append', row);

Answer (score 1):

I have to answer this to remind myself in future.

Refer: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/

```
rowAttributes: function (row, index) {
    return { "data-id": row.id };
},
```

This will add `data-id` to the `tr` element